# Set resolution of facebook canvas unity3d

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-canvas, facebook-unity-sdk

I have uploaded my unity game on webserver and its working on facebook. but i have facebook canvas resolution problem. as my game is in portrait mode. Screen resolution is 400 x 600..

How do i set this resolution in my unity project. as facebook settings is not allowing me to set canvas width.

We have method available : 
**FB.Canvas.SetResolution(int width , int height , bool fullscreen, int prefferedRefreshRate , Params Fbscreen.Layout[] layoutparams)**

i dnt knw which facebook layout parameter should i write.

Help me guys..

Thanks for your help and support.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using below code which is given in sample example of Facebook :

```
 #region FB.Canvas.SetResolution example

    public string Width = "800";
    public string Height = "600";
    public bool CenterHorizontal = true;
    public bool CenterVertical = false;
    public string Top = "10";
    public string Left = "10";

    public void CallCanvasSetResolution()
    {
        int width;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(Width, out width))
        {
            width = 800;
        }
        int height;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(Height, out height))
        {
            height = 600;
        }
        float top;
        if (!float.TryParse(Top, out top))
        {
            top = 0.0f;
        }
        float left;
        if (!float.TryParse(Left, out left))
        {
            left = 0.0f;
        }
        if (CenterHorizontal && CenterVertical)
        {
            FB.Canvas.SetResolution(width, height, false, 0, FBScreen.CenterVertical(), FBScreen.CenterHorizontal());
        } 
        else if (CenterHorizontal) 
        {
            FB.Canvas.SetResolution(width, height, false, 0, FBScreen.Top(top), FBScreen.CenterHorizontal());
        } 
        else if (CenterVertical)
        {
            FB.Canvas.SetResolution(width, height, false, 0, FBScreen.CenterVertical(), FBScreen.Left(left));
        }
        else
        {
            FB.Canvas.SetResolution(width, height, false, 0, FBScreen.Top(top), FBScreen.Left(left));
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

Hope it helps all of you.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Well i had a similar problem, if you need to set your game's resolution on Facebook Canvas through Unity's Web Player, you just need to:

```
Application.ExternalCall("IntegratedPluginCanvas.setResolution", width, height);
```

Getting a Web Player's game to work at an appropriate resolution on Facebook Canvas is a bit messy, specially if you have your own injected HTML on screen. I find myself building the game at a default resolution, setting another fixed height on the game's configuration on facebook's development backoffice, and another resolution through the above method.

Anyway, try this one :)